# How to bind a Telerik GridBoundColumn to an sql server 2008 xml column node using linq to sql

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, sql-server-2008, telerik-grid

I'm binding a radgrid using linq-to-sql, I'm binding the gird using this (cause I'll perform CRUD):

```
protected void RadGrid1_NeedDataSource(object sender, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)               {                         
RadGrid1.DataSource = DbContext.SucursalClienteProveedores;  
}
```

On my DB, I got a column named Contact, it is an Xml datatype and looks like this:

```
<contacto>
<nombre>Andrés Gutiérrez Hernández</nombre>
<cargo>CEO</cargo>
<telefono1>53-93-75-74</telefono1>
<telefono2>044-55-39-40-96-59</telefono2>
<email>gutierrez.andres@comprobantes.mx</email>
</contacto>
```

The rows look like this:

FIN020938SVR  |123  |FEAR3434   |Holly Molly|   |43         |Andrés Gutiérrez HernándezCEO53-93-75-74044-55-39-40-96-59gutierrez.andres@comprobantes.mx|0          |02/08/2011 12:00:00 a.m.

I'm trying to bind a GridBoundColumn to the node telefono1, on the designer I did the following:

```
 <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
        CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" ondeletecommand="RadGrid1_DeleteCommand"
        oninsertcommand="RadGrid1_InsertCommand" onitemcreated="RadGrid1_ItemCreated"
        onneeddatasource="RadGrid1_NeedDataSource"
        onupdatecommand="RadGrid1_UpdateCommand">
<MasterTableView  DataKeyNames="RFC,IDSucursal" CommandItemDisplay="Top" InsertItemPageIndexAction="ShowItemOnCurrentPage">
Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn  HeaderText="RFC" UniqueName="RFC" DataField="RFCCP">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Alias" UniqueName="Alias" DataField="NombreComercial">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Razon Social" UniqueName="razon_social" DataField="RazonSocial">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="TEL" UniqueName="Tel" DataField="Contacto.telefono1" >
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Email" UniqueName="Email" >
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
    </Columns>
         </MasterTableView>
         </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Of course the TEL column it's not retrieving any values, I could create a linq query and return a IEnumerable interface, but I was wondering if there's an easy way for this,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it's like normal XPATH navigation, but you could try:

```
DataField="Contacto/telefono1"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this above the MasterTableView

```
    <telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy runat="server" ID="RadAjaxManagerProxy1">
          <AjaxSettings>
         <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="btnAddCustomer">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadAjaxPanel1" />
            </UpdatedControls>
          </AjaxSettings>
   </telerik:RadAjaxManagerProxy>
```

And the RadGrid should be as follows

```
    <telerik:RadGrid ID="rgLeads" runat="server" Skin="Vista" Width="100%" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" AllowCustomPaging="true">
```

And in the code behind

```
    rgLeads.VirtualItemCount = 'stored proc here
    rgLeads.Rebind()
```